# How do I get the deployment id of an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a VM in Windows Azure and some networking people are asking me for the deployment id.  I cannot see this property anywhere on the portal.  How can I get the deployment id of a Windows Azure VM?  I just created the VM through the portal.

Comment: Did you create this VM using the Classic deployment model or the Resource Manager deployment model? It appears that the `deployment id` only applies in the Classic deployment model.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to:

1. Go to https://resources.azure.com and log in
2. Search for the name of your VM and click to open details. It should return JSON information about the VM.
3. In the JSON data, search for `deploymentId` (it should be under the `hardwareProfile` section in the JSON)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the deployment ID in the virtual machine's Dashboard tab. Refer to the screenshot-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it via Powershell:

First log in to azure:

```
login-AzureRmAccount
```

Then get a reference to the virtual machine. In my case, I have a virtual machine called `malcolms-dad` in the resource group `breaking-bad`:

```
$vm = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName breaking-bad -ResourceName malcolms-dad -ResourceType MicrosoftClassicComputer/virtualMachines)
```

Now you have the reference, you can query for the deployment id property:

```
$vm.Properties.HardwareProfile.DeploymentId
```

---

Note that we had to pass in the `-ResourceType` parameter into the `Get-AzureRmResource` query.  This might seem superfluous, but if you omit the parameter the command returns an object without the `Properties` field.